# How can I bind the action done in a UserControl to a control in the MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a simple WPF MVVM application that consist of a MainWindow with a button. I need to enable/disable this button depending on the validation of a TextBox that is part of UserControl (View) that is displayed in the main window.

I am able to display different views (one at a time) in the mainwindow. But I am not having any luck binding the validation results of (say a textbox or checkbox) to sync with the button (enable/disable) that is a part of the mainwindow.

Here is an example of my code:
MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ChildToParent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Name="MainGrid" Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="256"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="currentView" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    
    <Button Content="Submit" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,54,0" Padding="10,3,10,3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Name="buttonSubmit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="62">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                            <!--<Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxFirstName, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />-->
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

This is the ChildView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChildToParent.Views.ChildView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChildToParent.Validation"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="250" d:DesignWidth="520">
<Grid Height="250" Width="520" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="109" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Labels -->
    <TextBlock Text="FirstName" Margin="0,10,10,222" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="59" />

    <!-- TextBlocks -->
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxFirstName" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,225" Width="391" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:TextBoxNotEmptyValidationRule x:Name="FirstNameValidation" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" 
                                                         Message="You must enter a first name."/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

How can I bind the actions/results of a control that is part of a UserControl (textbox/checkbox), to trigger a control (button) that is part of the mainwindow?
I have googled this but have not found an example where this is possible am I doing something impossible here? I need your help....

Comment: Does it all have to be done in XAML, or might it make sense to add a NameIsValid boolean property to your ViewModel class and bind to that instead?

Comment: I tried that but was not successful